# How to use ontouchstart instead of onclick

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, onclick, ontouchstart

I am using the below code and it works on desktop but the click function is not working on mobile so I tried using ontouchstart but that is not working either.
What am I doing wrong?

```
var video = document.getElementById("myVideo");
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

function myFunction() {
    video.muted = !video.muted;
    btn.innerHTML = video.muted ? "Unmute":'Mute';
}
```

```
<section class="video-container">

  <div class="video-description">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>

  <video id="myVideo" autoplay loop>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>

  <div class="content">

    <button id="myBtn" class="" onclick="myFunction()">Mute</button>
   <button id="myBtn" class="mobile" ontouchstart="myFunction()">Mute</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: How are testing the mobile version?

Comment: Are you sure the JS is loaded after the HTML? And are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: Thanks, I uploaded example here: https://codepen.io/Teo10/pen/abMYMjd
If you test it on smaller browser screen you can see the button is not working

Answer (score 0):

**Try this. it may works on both desktop and mobile.**

```
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
btn.addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried that but didn't seem to work.
I uploaded an example here: codepen.io/Teo10/pen/abMYMjd

Comment: Ensure that there are no CSS issues preventing the button from receiving the touch event. Check for any overlapping elements or z-index issues.

Comment: Thanks, I checked the CSS and whether there are any overlapping elements but i think it's something else. 
https://codepen.io/Teo10/pen/abMYMjd

Comment: Also ensure that your viewport is properly configured for mobile devices.